# Access query won't work when dates have times

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query stated:

```
select *
from tblClient
where IntakeDate = #5/31/2011#
```

I know for a fact there are 8 records that have that date. But none of records with that date are pulled by this query. Those 8 records have times as well as "short date" (e.g. "5/31/2011 1:42:00 PM")

As a test I set the date to exactly 5/31/2011 for one record, and the query will work for that one record. Clearly the time value is interfering with this query.

I do not want to change all the date data to a strict 'short date' format and would like to work with it as-is. Can anyone give me some idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Why are you storing time values in a field called "IntakeDate"? Either the field is misnamed, or you're populating it with the wrong function (`Now()` includes the time part, while `Date()` is date only).

Comment: The data comes from another source that is imported into the database. I suppose I could strip the time before import.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: you are mistaken: the postfix `date` indicates a data element with a temporal element of any level of granularity, not just one day granularity. Citation for this is easy: the one and only book on SQL heuristics, 'Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style' (1.2.4, p.12, 'Standardized Postfixes').

Comment: "when dates have times": Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) has but one temporal data type, being `DATETIME`. As the name indicates, its domain values *all* contain a time element, even when that time element is equivalent to midnight.

Comment: ...While you can in theory restrict all `DATETIME` values within your data model (SQL DDL) to those having a time element equivalent to midnight (e.g. `CHECK` constraints or Validation Rules on all `DATETIME` columns etc), in practise it is easier to write SQL queries/update statements (SQL DML) to handle *all* `DATETIME` values in an appropriate way e.g. rounding in SQL code `DATETIME` parameter values passed to `PROCEDURE`s down to midnight.

Comment: @onedaywhen: you're harping on the wrong subject. The issue naming the field sensibly (so that the data stored in it means what the field's name implies) and populating the data properly (i.e., not inserting data that contradicts the meaning of the field. A field called "Invoice Date" should not have a MEANINGFUL time component -- all values stored in that field should be INTEGERS, with zero time component. That's all I'm talking about here. But you really know that, I'm sure.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "A field called `Invoice Date` should not have a MEANINGFUL time component" -- the `_date` postfix in a data element name suggests a temporal dimension, no more and no less.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "all values stored in that field should be INTEGERS, with zero time component" -- all temporal values should be relationally assigned using temporal functionality. Whether the data is physically stored as numeric, text or hieroglyphics should be of no conern. What *is* pertinent, however, is that Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) has no eqivalent of the SQL-92 `DATE` data type. It's sole temporal data type is the eqivalent of the SQL-92's `TIMESTAMP` (not to be confused with SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP`).

Comment: ...Therefore, given that you have to work with temporal data in Access (noting other SQLs are available :) and you want to use its temporal functionality (and I suggest you do) then time elements (meaningful or otherwise) cannot be elminiated in SQL and the best you can do is handle them in SQL.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: One imporant means of handling `DATETIME` values in Access is to use closed-open represntation of periods as suggested here (but not name-checked) by @Mitch Wheat. The `>=` indicates that the start date is within the period ('closed') and the `<` operator indicates the end date is not within the period ('open'). This is necessary for Access because its smallest time granule (fraction of a second) is undefined.

Comment: The OP appears to be using open-open representation at one day granularity, which is all too commonly seen in Accessland (and IIRC advocated by yourself!) and as a result we frequently see these kind of problems, hence questions on SO.

Comment: You understand exactly what I mean here, but you are pretending you don't and nattering on and on uselessly. I'm finished here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a condition that encompasses a single day's time range:

```
select *
from tblClient
where IntakeDate >= #5/31/2011# AND < #6/1/2011#
```

[You could use the [`DateValue()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datevalue-function-HA001228814.aspx) function on your column, but that would prevent any index being used.]

Comment: I wish Devin's solution worked since it's much more elegant. But I'm going with a variant of this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I would say this one is superior because it uses the indexes, as Mitch points out.

Comment: "encompasses a single day's time range... to '5/31/2011 23:59:59.999' -- Actually, with Access (ACE, Jet, whatever), the value `2011-05-31T23:59:59.999` when cast to its `DATETIME` data type -- it has but one temporal data type -- will round to `2011-06-01` e.g. try this in Access: `SELECT MONTH(CDATE(DATESERIAL(2011, 5, 31) + TIMESERIAL(23, 59, 59) + (TIMESERIAL(0, 0, 1) * 999 / 1000)));` -- returns `6` i.e. rounded to June.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think your predicate is correct. However, you made a misstatement about the granularity of `DATETIME` values in Access.

Answer (score 2):

The DateValue function truncates the time off the date

```
select *
from tblClient
where DateValue(IntakeDate) = #5/31/2011#
```

Comment: This returns "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: You get Data type mismatch because DateValue can't handle Nulls.

Comment: That's good to know. Maybe I can use this solution... thanks.

Comment: This won't use indexes, so to me the other solution is superior.