# MS Access Date() yields no results

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've searched but been unable to figure this out. I used to use MS Access many many years ago but have switched mostly to PHP and MySQL to do my work. But when I"m at work, I have to use those resources.

Trying to build a basic query from an ODBC connection to a SQL Server. One of the columns is a date field (SQL server field type: datetime).

When I build the query and enter Date() for my Where clause should be it yields no results.

```
SELECT dbo_Order.OrderStatusID,
    dbo_Order.FillerOrderNumber,
    dbo_Order.RelevantClinicalInfo,
    dbo_Order.ReasonForStudy,
    dbo_Order.ProcedureDescList,
    dbo_Order.PlacerFld2 AS Modality,
    dbo_Order.ScheduleDate,
    dbo_Order.ExplorerStatus,
    dbo_Order.SiteID
FROM dbo_Order
WHERE (
        (
            (dbo_Order.PlacerFld2) = "CRFL"
            OR (dbo_Order.PlacerFld2) = "CT"
            OR (dbo_Order.PlacerFld2) = "SAMR"
            )
        AND ((dbo_Order.ScheduleDate) = DATE ())
        AND ((dbo_Order.ExplorerStatus) = "SCHEDULED")
        AND ((dbo_Order.SiteID) = 1)
        );
```

I've tried also doing something like Date: Format([ScheduleDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") but this also returns no results.

MS Access 2016
SQL Server 2008

Comment: Is this query based on querying an ODBC query / linked table, or an ODBC query itself? It looks like it's an ODBC query, therefore you would not use DATE(), as that is not a SQL function (to recieve a current date), use `GETDATE()`

Comment: Does your ScheduleDate include any time values. Date() returns 1/1/2018 00:00 as a default so if your Scheduled date is 1/1/2018 04:34:00 it won't match. try using DateValue([ScheduleDate]) to return just the date.

Comment: Try with a fixed value: `dbo_Order.ScheduleDate = #2018/07/10#`, using a date that exists in the table, of course. That has to work.

Comment: Thanks, @Minty that worked exactly. I had no idea to try that so I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

If your ScheduleDate include any time values, Date() returns 1/1/2018 00:00 as a default so if your Scheduled date is 1/1/2018 04:34:00 it won't match.

Try using DateValue([ScheduleDate]) to return just the date

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer:

```
dbo_Order.ScheduleDate >= Date() AND dbo_Order.ScheduleDate < Date() + 1
```

`DateValue([ScheduleDate])`has to be computed on every row and can't use an index (if any) what can affect query performance on huge data. See [Access query won't work when dates have times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687037/access-query-wont-work-when-dates-have-times#answer-6687054) In addition DateValue can't handle NULL values.